# Firebase Cloud Messaging on Web - send message via postman

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging for Web. I managed to initialize it correctly and get the token:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "name.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-name",
    storageBucket: "project-name.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1111111111111"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
    })

    messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
        console.log("token: " + currentToken);
    })
</script>
```

+manifest.json with gcm_sender_id

I can see I am getting the token in the console so I am trying to validate it and send my first notification via Postman - [here is the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message).

Post url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**PROJECTID**/messages:send 
Authorization: No Auth

Header

[image]

Body - the token is from the **client side function** `messaging.getToken().then(function(currentToken) {...`

[image]

When I post it, I am getting error 401 UNAUTHENTICATED with following details:

```
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
```

Any suggestions how to authorize it correctly in postman and test it out? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate an access token for your firebase project. Example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token)

and use it below

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer {{access token value}}" -H 
"Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{
    "message":{
     ....
    },
    "token": "{{device token}}"
    }
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{{project-name}}/messages:send"
```

Comment: This seems to create a json object with a private key in that is a multi line thing. I think I just want a simple jwt?